Looker Studio Viewer's Credentials is not working with Big Query resource
I have created a report in Looker Studio from my Big Query table and when I shared this report with recipient@gmail.com it worked as expected and recipient could see and edit the report perfectly.
Then for my data source inside data credentials, I changed the permission to Viewer's Credentials

After this, my report stopped working on the recipient side and showed this error:

I added the recipient@gmail.com inside my Big Query table so to make sure the recipient has access to data but still getting the same error. Also, there is a lot less documentation online regarding Viewer's Credentials so want to know if anyone has come across this issue.

In the above image, all of the roles have Principle with email recipient@gmail.com

with these permissions, a viewer can see all BigQuery tables, except those that have granular row-level access. Can the viewer see and query the tables directly in BigQuery?

@aliizadi No I mean I don't want to add users in my cloud console to interact with Big Query instead I was only adding their emails for a Specific table so at least they can see the report in Looker with their credentials. Do I have to add them in IAM?
